# Matmul in Fortran

Tags: python, fortran

I obtain different results from matmul in Fortran and Python. How to get the right one in Fortran. B is probably not understood as a 3x3 matrix. How to solve it, please?

k = 1
m = 3

In Fortran, I have:

```
 A(k:m,k):  0.88807383397711526       0.32505758367186816       0.32505758367186816     
 B(k:m,k:m):   1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000       -1.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000
```

matmul gives

```
1.5381890013208515      -0.56301625030524716        1.2131314176489834
```

In Python, I have:

```
A[k,k:m] [ 0.888074  0.325058  0.325058]
B[k:m,k:m] [[ 1.000000  1.000000  1.000000]
 [-1.000000  0.000000  1.000000]
 [ 1.000000  0.000000  1.000000]]
```

matmul gives

```
 [ 0.888074  0.888074  1.538189]
```

Comment: Please show us the code you are using. Without that everything is guess work. Also you seem to have different A's one is a row vector, the other a column vector. Finally given the simple form of B and the small matrices have you worked out by hand what the correct answer should be?

Comment: Did you try transposing either of the matrices? Does that give you a hint as to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the order of the multiplication. Numpy considers 1D arrays without treating it as a row or column vector.

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([0.88807383397711526, 0.32505758367186816, 0.32505758367186816])
B = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [-1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]], dtype=float)
```

If you do `A@B`, which is the same as `np.matmul(A,B)`, assuming `A` is actually a "1D row array", you get

```py
>>> A@B
array([0.88807383, 0.88807383, 1.538189  ])
```

But if you do the opposite, i.e. `B@A` which is the same as `np.matmul(B,A)`, assuming `A` is actually a "1D column array" you get

```py
>>> B@A
array([ 1.538189  , -0.56301625,  1.21313142])
```

---